# Wordpress homepage 302 redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies, http-status-code-302

I'm having a really hard time with an issue since 2 days, three different freelancers couldn't fix it neither.
My wordpress homepage (static page) started to behave like a 302 redirect loop while it was working fine before ([www.scrybs.com](http://www.scrybs.com)). My wordpress is installed in a folder but it can't be the issue because it was working fine before.
My Site URL in admin is with www. but when accessing to without www, it shows the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/****/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 925

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/****/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 943

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/****/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:925) in /home/****/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228
```

What I know about it:

- It doesn't come from htaccess (tried to rename it)
- It doesn't come from any plugin (deactivated them all)
- Edit: Also doesn't come from the them (switched it)
- If you access another page and go back to homepage then, it works
- If you access another page, delete cache and cookies and access the homepage then, it's not working (cookie related?)

Thanks in advance for your help.